# Flutter - Application-Wide 'Services'

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking into Flutter and was wondering the best or correct way to do this:

If I have a 'common' object that provides functionality that's useful throughout an application what's the best way to make it easily available?

E.g. I have a service class I want to be available throughout my application on various pages/screens

```
class MyService{

  bool available = true;

  bool validString(String s) =>  true;

  bool validNum(num n) => true;

  void someFunc() => print("Called");

  String formatString(String s) => "Formatted String";

  String defaultString() => "Default String";

  // ....

}
```

The best example I came across for doing this starts by initialising a single instance of this class on application start in `main.dart` (first line)

```
MyService service = new MyService();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Then any route/screen/widget that needs the service imports main and just calls it via the previously initialised object

```
import 'main.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              service.defaultString(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => service.available ? service.someFunc() : print("Service Unavailable"),
        tooltip: 'Validate',
        child: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this methodology is fine as there's one instance only, which any change to its parameters will immediately be reflected in the other widgets/classes that use it. And it can also be accessed from anywhere in your code.
   One of the other great points about this approach is that you don't have to update the `State` of any `Stateful widget` which depends on this object explicitly, any change on it will fire the `setState()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply (will give it an hour or so to see if there are any other answers) - I agree with your reasoning but should I also use a different method for access / listening to data changes like scoped model?

Comment: no problem. I am a strong proponent of this approach of using objects as it cause dependent stateful widgets to call their `setState` function automatically, which saves alot of precious time.

Answer (score 0):

For state management you may want to try [RxVMS](https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/rxvms-a-practical-architecture-for-flutter-apps/)